# Spring boot validation - MethodArgumentNotValidException when validate form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hello i'm relative new to Spring, i try to validate a form with jakarta.validation. I'm trying to get an error message in the form when I type a BigInteger number less than 0.5. The validation seems to be going well, as I have a 400 BAD_REQUEST, only that my code in the controller doesn't execute, and the application crashes instead of printing the errors in the form . This is the error:

> DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public java.lang.String com.example.demo.controller.BasicController.salvaEvento(com.example.demo.model.Evento,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult): [Field error in object 'eventissimo' on field 'prezzo': rejected value [0.1]; codes [DecimalMin.eventissimo.prezzo,DecimalMin.prezzo,DecimalMin.java.math.BigDecimal,DecimalMin]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [eventissimo.prezzo,prezzo]; arguments []; default message [prezzo],true,0.50]; default message [deve essere superiore a o uguale a 0.50]] ]

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvaevento", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String salvaEvento(@Valid @ModelAttribute("eventissimo") Evento eventissimo,
            Model model, BindingResult bindingResult){
        
        System.out.println("PRINT THIS LINE");// Message not printed

        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return"aggiungievento";
        }

        //other things
        
        return "aggiungievento"; // My form
    }
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "evento")
public class Evento {
    @Id
    @Column(name= "idevento")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nome", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String nomeevento;

    @Column(name = "prezzo", nullable = false)
    @NotNull @DecimalMin(value = "0.50")
    private BigDecimal prezzo;
   //other things
```

View:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/salvaevento}" method="post">
// things
<div th:object="${eventissimo}">

<p>Prezzo biglietto:</p>
<input type="number" name="prezzo" id="prezzo" placeholder="Inserisci un prezzo tra 2 e 250"
required="required" step="any"  th:field="*{prezzo}"/>
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('prezzo')}" th:errors="*{prezzo}">Prezzo minimo 0.5</span>
```

I mainly followed this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/, But no error is printed on the form.

I put a breakpoint in my controller and found that the code doesn't execute. I try to implemets the @ExceptionHandler Annotation. But the application still has a different error related to the template. I mainly followed this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ModelAndView  handleException(Model model,MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
        String customException = exception.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
                       .map(x -> x.getField() + x.getDefaultMessage())
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        
     // Re-inizializza l'oggetto "eventissimo" e i dati necessari nel model
        ModelAndView nevv = new ModelAndView("aggiungievento");
        Evento nuovoEvento = new Evento();
        Iterable<Tipologia> tipoT = tipologiaRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("validationErrors", customException); 
        nevv.addObject("eventissimo", nuovoEvento);
        nevv.addObject("tipologie", tipoT);
        return nevv;
        
    }
```

This are the errors:

> Using resolved error view: ModelAndView [view="aggiungievento"; model={validationErrors=prezzodeve essere superiore a o uguale a 0.50, eventissimo=com.example.demo.model.Evento@1d84a691, tipologie=[com.example.demo.model.Tipologia@3e4590a3, com.example.demo.model.Tipologia@202e1baf, com.example.demo.model.Tipologia@2954863, com.example.demo.model.Tipologia@fe35999]}]

> THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-8] Exception processing template "aggiungievento": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/aggiungievento.html]")

> Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringSelectFieldTagProcessor' (template: "aggiungievento" - line 48, col 13)

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'tipologia' of bean class [com.example.demo.model.Evento]: Value of nested property 'tipologia' is null

And the view:

```
<select th:field="*{tipologia.idtipologia}"> (LINE 48)
<option th:each="tipo : ${tipologie}" th:value="${tipo.idtipologia}" th:text="${tipo.tipologia}"></option>
</select>
```

Need help, tks

EDIT: Simply swapping the method parameter between BindingResult and Model now works. To work, BindingResult must be passed immediately after the attribute to be validated ( @Valid).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/salvaevento", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String salvaEvento(@Valid @ModelAttribute("eventissimo") Evento eventissimo,BindingResult bindingResult,Model model)
```